# How did Solo (and some others) survive Silo 17's destruction?

Tags: wool

In the second book of the *Silo* saga, *Shift*, we learn that Solo witnessed the destruction of his Silo. He also notes the releasing of a gas, but doesn't seem to care about it.

Later, in *Dust*, we learn that

> the destruction of a Silo consists in **opening the top door** and **releasing a lethal gas**.

However, Solo and other Silo 17 inhabitants (people he killed, and some children) survived the destruction. How?

Comment: I was half-way through adding `star-wars` and `han-solo` tags, and then posting a rant about correctly tagging your stuff. And then I read below the title.

Comment: @Gallifreian Yeah, there is maybe too much Star Wars here :-p

Comment: Have you read all 3 books? This is explained later

Comment: @user20310, yes I did, but I may have forgotten some parts... I have memories about general panic, people trying to get out (and dying) and this gas.

Comment: @Bebs someone in silo one (can't remember who) rejigs the pipes so the silo gets the good nanos instead of the bad ones (hence the long life of those alive and good state of the bodies of those who died)